# How can i specify product version when working with migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

Here is a quick sample on how the `[dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]` table looks like:

[image: EF migrations table]

Is there a way to specify the `ProductVersion` when applying migrations?

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to set it, as this is EF version.

Comment: My ideea behind this was to specify the release version of the software using major, minor versioning. This way keeping track with the actual CI flow.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything with this table. It's for EF's internal use only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't change the value in that column--it's used internally by EF.

You can add a new column if you like by overriding the `IHistoryRepository` service. See [Custom EF Core Migrations History Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table) to get started.

Comment: Note: changing it is not recommended as it can lead to breaking changes down the line as they specify in the article. Same for the **SqliteHistoryRepository** that I was looking into.